# Module parse failed in native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, react-native-web

[image: Error]

I want to see my app on the webpage so what do I do? I followed this link
https://github.com/simonqian/react-helloworld
But I didn't get an answer? So pls provide some links to solve the issue

After I started the npm using npm start I faced this type of error? How to resolve this?

This is my web.config.js file. My configuration file will be in the root directory

```js
'use strict';

const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: 'E:/react/webnative/main.js',

  output: {
    // path: 'E:/',
    filename: 'index.js',
  },

  devServer: {
    inline: false,
    port: 7777,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: ['pug-loader?self'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        //exclude:/(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [new UglifyJSPlugin()],
};
```

Comment: Does your app.jsx file have to be .jsx? The error is clearly stating that it cannot read that file type

Comment: try `import App from ./App` and change jsx with js

Comment: import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

This is my main.js fileimport App from './App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);

Comment: This is my App.jsx                                                                                                   import React from 'react';

    class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>hello world!!!</div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;

Comment: Please see my answer below if you want to use .jsx file extension. If you dont, save that file as .js and change it inside in main also

Answer (score 0):

Your web pack config should look something like this to read .jsx files:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app/assets/frontend/myFile.jsx',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/app/assets/javascripts',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
   loaders: [{
     test: /\.jsx?$/,
     loader: 'babel',
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     query: {
       cacheDirectory: true,
       presets: ['react', 'es2015']
     }
   }]
 }
}
```

Or just dont use jsx. Hope this Helps!

Comment: 'use strict';

module.exports = {
 entry: 'E:/react/webnative/main.js',
        output: {
          filename: 'index.js'
        },

      devServer: {
        inline : false,
        port: 7777
      },
 resolve :{
   extensions : ['.js','.jsx']
 },
  module: {
   loaders: [
          {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,           
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
              cacheDirectory : true,
              presets: ["es2015", "react"]
            }
          }
        ]
  },

Comment: @Jeyasri.R What is this? What are you telling me here? A bit of context would be lovely

Comment: sorry for the delay respone . I would like to do run my native app on Web-browser , so what I do ? I followed this link https://github.com/simonqian/react-helloworld

Comment: @Jeyasri.R As i mentioned in my answer, your webpack.config.js file is wrong. From looking at that github page you need to add this: resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  }, into your webpack.config.js file

Comment: yes I added Still it shows error . I refered more link but i cant resolve the problem @ShaneG